# selector + csv //

Tags: php

Существует форма регистрации, в которой необходимо выбирать страны из списка. Этот список хранится в csv файле, как мне его достать оттуда и положить в selector  , то есть страны - выпадающий список

Comment: Вы бы структуру csv-файла опубликовали бы в вопросе. А вообще можно [прочитать](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) файл в цикле, формируя в теле цикла необходимые html-теги _(в вашем случае `<select>`)_.